kalman filter constant accelaration model
i am trying to understand the kalman filter constant acceleration model(CA) through simulations but the results are not as expected but when i did the simulation in similar way for CV model i got good results however transition to CA has not been easy so i am trying to understand where i am going wrong
i have 3 measurements obtained from radar: range(r), azimuth(θ), radial velocity(v) i am converting them to x,y,vx and vy using the equations
$$x = rcosθ\\ 
y = rsinθ\\
    vx = vcosθ\\
    vy = vsinθ$$
my state matrix is
$$\text{CA_FILTX} = \begin{bmatrix}x \\y \\vx \\vy \\ax \\ay\end{bmatrix}
$$
and observation matrix
$$\text{H} = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$
state transition matrix
$$\text{CA_PHI} = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & T & 0 & 
\frac{T^2}{2} & 0\\0 & 1 & 0 &  T & 0 & \frac{T^2}{2}\\0 &  0 & 1 & 0 & T & 0\\0  & 0 &  0  & 1 &   0  &   T\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  1 & 0\\ 0 &  0  & 0 &  0  & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$
process noise covariance matrix
$$\text{Q} = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{T^5}{20} & 0 & \frac{T^4}{8} & 0 & \frac{T^3}{6} & 0 \\
0 & \frac{T^5}{20} & 0 & \frac{T^4}{8} & 0 & \frac{T^3}{6} \\
\frac{T^4}{8} & 0 & \frac{T^3}{3} & 0 & \frac{T^2}{2} & 0 \\
0 & \frac{T^4}{8} & 0 & \frac{T^3}{3} & 0 & \frac{T^2}{2} \\
\frac{T^3}{6} & 0 & \frac{T^2}{2} & 0 & T & 0 \\
0 & \frac{T^3}{6} & 0 & \frac{T^2}{2} & 0 & T
\end{bmatrix}$$
and the measurement noise covariance matrix in polar where Sigma_Rng,Sigma_Azi and Sigma_vel are standard deviation of measurement error
$$
\text{Sigma_matrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
\text{Sigma_Rng}^2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \text{Sigma_Azi}^2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \text{Sigma_vel}^2
\end{bmatrix}$$
i am calculating the mesurement noise covariance matrix R with the help of jacobian matrix
$$\text{R} = \text{jacobian_matrix} \cdot \text{Sigma_matrix} \cdot \text{jacobian_matrix}^T$$
the jacobian matrix i am using is
$$\text{jacobian_matrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
\cosθ & -\text{r} \sinθ & 0 \\
\sinθ & \text{r} \cosθ & 0 \\
0 & -\text{v} \sin\theta & \cos\theta \\
0 & \text{v} \cos\theta & \sin\theta
\end{bmatrix}$$
and i am using the fallowing equation to estimate my states
$$\text{CA_PRED} = \text{CA_PHI} \cdot \text{CA_FILTX}$$
$$\text{CA_PRED_COV} = \left( \text{CA_PHI} \cdot \text{CA_FILTX_COV} \cdot \text{CA_PHI}^T \right) + Q$$
$$\text{meas_matrix} = \begin{bmatrix}x \\y \\vx \\vy \end{bmatrix}$$
$$\text{CA_innovation} = \text{meas_matrix} - (H \cdot \text{CA_PRED})$$
$$\text{S} = (H \cdot \text{CA_PRED_COV} \cdot H^T) + R$$
$$\text{K} = \text{CA_PRED_COV} \cdot H^T \cdot S^{-1}$$
$$\text{CA_FILTX}  = \text{CA_PRED}\ + (\text{K} \cdot \text{CA_innovation})$$
$$
\text{CA_FILTX_COV} = \text{CA_PRED_COV} - (K \cdot H \cdot \text{CA_PRED_COV})
$$
my simulated results are this way  

but i expected my acceleration to become constant after some time
so here are my list of doubts

the matrices i am using are they correct
am i taking care of the noise correctly?
the jacobian matrix i used is it correct?

as per the request i am attaching my matlab code here
%section 1: generating measurements
  start_range = 2000;
  azimuth = 30;
  v = 2;
  accel = 0.1;
  deltaT = 1;
  total_duration = 100;
  tgttype = 'incoming';

  time_vec = 0:deltaT:total_duration;
  num_samples = length(time_vec);

  sigma_range = 3;
  sigma_azimuth = 0.05;
  sigma_velocity = 0.5;

  range_noise = normrnd(0, sigma_range, [1, num_samples]);
  azimuth_noise = normrnd(0, sigma_azimuth, [1, num_samples]);
  velocity_noise = normrnd(0, sigma_velocity, [1, num_samples]);

  true_range = zeros(1, num_samples);
  true_azimuth = zeros(1, num_samples);
  true_vel = zeros(1, num_samples);
  meas_range = zeros(1, num_samples);
  meas_azimuth = zeros(1, num_samples);
  meas_vel = zeros(1, num_samples);

  truefid = fopen("CA_trueval.txt","w");
  measfid = fopen("CA_measurements.txt","w");

  true_range(1) = start_range;
  true_azimuth(1) = azimuth;
  true_vel(1) = v;
  fprintf(truefid,"%d  %f  %f  %f %f\n",1,true_range(1),true_azimuth(1),true_vel(1),accel);

  for i = 2:num_samples
    true_vel(i) = v + (accel*time_vec(i));

    if tgttype == 'outgoing'
      true_range(i) = start_range + (true_vel(i)*time_vec(i));
    elseif tgttype == 'incoming'
      true_range(i) = start_range - (true_vel(i)*time_vec(i));
    end
    true_azimuth(i) = azimuth;
    fprintf(truefid,"%d  %f  %f  %f %f\n",i,true_range(i),true_azimuth(i),true_vel(i),accel);
  endfor

  % Adding noise to true measurements
  meas_range = true_range + range_noise;
  meas_azimuth = true_azimuth + azimuth_noise;
  meas_vel = true_vel + velocity_noise;

  for j = 1:num_samples
    fprintf(measfid,"%d  %f  %f  %f\n",j,meas_range(j),meas_azimuth(j),meas_vel(j));
  end
  fclose(measfid);
  fclose(truefid);

  %section 2: kalman filter part
  predfid = fopen("CA_Pred.txt","w");
  filtfid = fopen("CA_filt.txt","w");

  fprintf(predfid,"%d %f  %f  %f %f\n",1,0,0,0,0);
  fprintf(filtfid,"%d %f  %f  %f %f\n",1,0,0,0,0);

  T = deltaT;

  T2 = T^2;
  T3 = T^3;
  T4 = T^4;
  T5 = T^5;

  %observation matrix
  H = [ 1 0 0 0 0 0
  0 1 0 0 0 0
  0 0 1 0 0 0
  0 0 0 1 0 0];

  %state transition matrix
  CA_PHI = [1   0   T   0   T2/2  0
  0   1   0   T   0     T2/2
  0   0   1   0   T     0
  0   0   0   1   0     T
  0   0   0   0   1     0
  0   0   0   0   0     1];

  % process noise covariance matrix
  Q = [T5/20   0       T4/8    0       T3/6    0
  0       T5/20   0       T4/8    0       T3/6
  T4/8    0       T3/3    0       T2/2    0
  0       T4/8    0       T3/3    0       T2/2
  T3/6    0       T2/2    0       T       0
  0       T3/6    0       T2/2    0       T];

  %measurement noise covariance polar
  Sigma_matrix = [ sigma_range^2    0                 0
  0              sigma_azimuth^2   0
  0              0                 sigma_velocity^2];

  measured_data = load('CA_measurements.txt');

  rng = measured_data(1,2);
  az = measured_data(1,3);
  v = measured_data(1,4);
  accel = (measured_data(2,4) - measured_data(1,4)) / deltaT

  x = rng * cos(deg2rad(az));
  y = rng * sin(deg2rad(az));
  vx = v * cos(deg2rad(az));
  vy = v * sin(deg2rad(az));
  ax = accel * cos(deg2rad(az));
  ay = accel * sin(deg2rad(az));

  %state matrix
  CA_FILTX = [x
  y
  vx
  vy
  ax
  ay];

  %intial filter covariance (taking identity matrix)
  CA_FILTX_COV = eye(6);

  for i = 2:num_samples

    CA_PRED = CA_PHI * CA_FILTX;
    CA_PRED_COV = (CA_PHI * CA_FILTX_COV * CA_PHI') + Q;

    range = measured_data(i,2);
    azi = measured_data(i,3);
    vel = measured_data(i,4);

    new_x = range * cos(deg2rad(azi));
    new_y = range * sin(deg2rad(azi));
    new_vx = vel * cos(deg2rad(azi));
    new_vy = vel * sin(deg2rad(azi));

    jacobian_matrix = [ cos(deg2rad(azi))    -1*range*sin(deg2rad(azi))     0
    sin(deg2rad(azi))     range*cos(deg2rad(azi))       0
    0                     -1*vel*sin(deg2rad(azi))      cos(deg2rad(azi))
    0                     vel*cos(deg2rad(azi))         sin(deg2rad(azi))];

    %measurement noise covariance cartesian
    R = jacobian_matrix * Sigma_matrix * jacobian_matrix';

    meas_matrix = [new_x
    new_y
    new_vx
    new_vy];

    CA_innovation = meas_matrix - (H * CA_PRED);
    S = (H * CA_PRED_COV * H') + R;
    K = CA_PRED_COV * H' * inv(S);

    CA_FILTX = CA_PRED + (K * CA_innovation);
    CA_FILTX_COV = CA_PRED_COV - (K * H * CA_PRED_COV);

    pred_range = sqrt((CA_PRED(1,1)*CA_PRED(1,1)) + (CA_PRED(2,1)*CA_PRED(2,1)));
    pred_azi = rad2deg(atan2(CA_PRED(2,1), CA_PRED(1,1)));
    pred_vel = sqrt((CA_PRED(3,1)*CA_PRED(3,1)) + (CA_PRED(4,1)*CA_PRED(4,1)));
    pred_accel = sqrt((CA_PRED(5,1)*CA_PRED(5,1)) + (CA_PRED(6,1)*CA_PRED(6,1)));

    filt_range = sqrt((CA_FILTX(1,1)*CA_FILTX(1,1)) + (CA_FILTX(2,1)*CA_FILTX(2,1)));
    filt_azi = rad2deg(atan2(CA_FILTX(2,1), CA_FILTX(1,1)));
    filt_vel = sqrt((CA_FILTX(3,1)*CA_FILTX(3,1)) + (CA_FILTX(4,1)*CA_FILTX(4,1)));
    filt_accel = sqrt((CA_FILTX(5,1)*CA_FILTX(5,1)) + (CA_FILTX(6,1)*CA_FILTX(6,1)));

    fprintf(predfid,"%d %f  %f  %f %f\n",i,pred_range,pred_azi,pred_vel,pred_accel);
    fprintf(filtfid,"%d %f  %f  %f %f\n",i,filt_range,filt_azi,filt_vel,filt_accel);
  endfor
  fclose(predfid);
  fclose(filtfid);

  meas_rng = measured_data(:,2);
  meas_azi = measured_data(:,3);
  meas_vel = measured_data(:,4);

  pred_data = load('CA_Pred.txt');
  prd_rng = pred_data(:,2);
  prd_azi = pred_data(:,3);
  prd_vel = pred_data(:,4);
  prd_accel = pred_data(:,5);

  true_data = load('CA_trueval.txt');
  true_rng = true_data(:,2);
  true_azi = true_data(:,3);
  true_vel = true_data(:,4);
  true_accel = true_data(:,5);

  filter_data = load('CA_filt.txt');
  flt_rng = filter_data(:,2);
  flt_azi = filter_data(:,3);
  flt_vel = filter_data(:,4);
  flt_accel = filter_data(:,5);

  figure;
  plot(true_rng,'go-',meas_rng,'ko-', prd_rng,'bo-',flt_rng,'ro-');
  title('CA model Range');
  legend('true range','Measured Range','pred range','filt range');

  figure;
  plot(true_azi,'go-',meas_azi,'ko-',prd_azi,'bo-',flt_azi,'ro-');
  title('CA model Azimuth ');
  legend('True Azimuth', 'Measured Azimuth','pred azimuth','filt azi');

  figure;
  plot(true_vel,'go-',meas_vel,'ko-',prd_vel,'bo-',flt_vel,'ro-');
  title('CA model Velocity ');
  legend('True Velocity','measured vel','pred velocity','filter vel');

  figure;
  plot(true_accel,'go-',prd_accel,'bo-',flt_accel,'ro-');
  title('CA model Accelaration ');
  legend('True accelaration','pred accelaration','filter accelaration');

i hope i have given clear picture of my problem please help me understand what is the issue and how do i solve it. Any suggestion/help will be very much appreciated,looking forward to learn more about kalman filter. Thanks in advance for any help

Can you write out your equations using Latex?

@Baddioes i have edited the question and wrote my equation using Latex

Can you post your data files, and the whole code so I can reproduce the results myself and try some things out?

@Baddioes thanks for the reply i have posted my full code here and the data files will be generated when you run the code so i have not provided them separately please do check and let me know if anything else is required from my end

I don't think your matrices are necessarily incorrect, but I think you have maybe a misunderstanding about the Kalman filter. Because the Kalman filter uses a linear model, the measured data can be seen as the predicted data plus some noise. So, you start out with an initial guess and then propagate it through the state-space equations to generate your data, otherwise you will violate the Kalman filter assumptions. I'll try to write up something in the morning.

one more doubt is the way i am generating measurement data(true data+noise) is that correct? i have simulated my measurement this way with the assumption that radar measurements have gaussian noise

Just verifying, this isn't a homework question, is it?

Your $vx$ and $vy$ are not the time derivatives of $x$ and $y$. The correct expression for the velocities would be $dx/dt=v\cos(\theta)-r\sin(\theta)d\theta/dt$ and $dy/dt=v\sin(\theta)+r\cos(\theta)d\theta/dt$.

no its not homework question i am trying to understand the CA model and trying to verify why my results are not the way i expected if my measurement generation is wrong or not

@fibonatic thanks for the reply  i will check this

I'll explain this in more general terms as it'll be easier. Let's assume we have true target state $\underline{x}$, estimated target state $\underline{\hat{x}}$, measurement $\underline{z}$, state transition matrix $\mathbf{F}$, and observation matrix $\mathbf{H}$. In real world scenarios, all that's needed is the Kalman loop because $\underline{z}$ is generated from actually collected data. But in simulation land, the data has to be simulated according to the linear data model. So first you want to simulate all your data according to the state-space equations, given by
\begin{align}
\underline{z}_{k} &= \mathbf{H}\underline{x}_{k}\\
\underline{x}_{k+1} &= \mathbf{F}\underline{x}_{k}
\end{align}
Then, we set $\hat{\underline{x}}_{0|-1} = \underline{x}_{0} + \underline{w}$, ie, the initial prediction is some guess relatively in the range of the true values. For reference, the notation $\underline{y}_{k|k}$ is the filtered value at time $k$, and the notation $\underline{y}_{k|k-1}$ is the predicted value at time $k$ from the previous $k-1$ samples. From here, we can go through the Kalman loop
\begin{align}
\underline{\epsilon}_{k} &= \underline{z}_{k} - \mathbf{H}\underline{\hat{x}}_{k|k-1} \\ \mathbf{S} &= \mathbf{H}\mathbf{P}_{k|k-1}\mathbf{H}^{T} + \mathbf{R} \\ \mathbf{K} &= \mathbf{P}_{k|k-1}\mathbf{H}\mathbf{S}^{-1} \\ \underline{\hat{x}}_{k|k} &= \underline{\hat{x}}_{k|k-1} + \mathbf{K}\underline{\epsilon}_{k} \\ \mathbf{P}_{k|k} &= \left(\mathbf{I} - \mathbf{K}\mathbf{H}\right)\mathbf{P}_{k|k-1} \\ \underline{\hat{x}}_{k+1|k} &= \mathbf{F}\underline{\hat{x}}_{k|k} \\ \mathbf{P}_{k+1|k} &= \mathbf{F}\mathbf{P}_{k|k}\mathbf{F}^{T} + \mathbf{Q}
\end{align}
EDIT: Since this isn't a homework question, below is the code I posted to generate the data. It may not all be right, but it gives something better.
  % ADDED MY CODE
  X = zeros(size(CA_FILTX_COV,1),num_samples);
  Y = zeros(size(H,1),num_samples);
  X(:,1) = [start_range*cosd(azimuth); start_range*sind(azimuth); v*cosd(azimuth); v*sind(azimuth); accel*cosd(azimuth); accel*sind(azimuth)];
  for ii = 1:num_samples
      ang(ii) = atand(X(2,ii)/X(1,ii));
      r(ii) = sqrt(X(1,ii).^2+X(2,ii).^2);
      vel(ii) = sqrt(X(3,ii).^2+X(4,ii).^2);
      J = [ cos(deg2rad(ang(ii)))    -1*r(ii)*sin(deg2rad(ang(ii)))     0
      sin(deg2rad(ang(ii)))     r(ii)*cos(deg2rad(ang(ii)))       0
      0                     -1*vel(ii)*sin(deg2rad(ang(ii)))      cos(deg2rad(ang(ii)))
      0                     vel(ii)*cos(deg2rad(ang(ii)))         sin(deg2rad(ang(ii)))];
      Y(:,ii) = H*X(:,ii) + J*Sigma_matrix*randn(3,1); % Measurement
      if ii ~= num_samples
        X(:,ii+1) = CA_PHI*X(:,ii) + [randn(size(CA_PHI,1)-2,1); 0; 0]; % State Transition
      end
  end

  Xpred = zeros(size(X));
  Xpred(:,1) = CA_FILTX + randn(size(CA_FILTX));
  Xfilt = zeros(size(Xpred));
  E = zeros(size(Y));

  for ii = 1:num_samples
      % Xf = CA_PHI*Xfilt(:,ii-1);
      ang(ii) = atand(Y(2,ii)/Y(1,ii));
      r(ii) = sqrt(Y(1,ii).^2+Y(2,ii).^2);
      vel(ii) = sqrt(Y(3,ii).^2+Y(4,ii).^2);
      J = [ cos(deg2rad(ang(ii)))    -1*r(ii)*sin(deg2rad(ang(ii)))     0
      sin(deg2rad(ang(ii)))     r(ii)*cos(deg2rad(ang(ii)))       0
      0                     -1*vel(ii)*sin(deg2rad(ang(ii)))      cos(deg2rad(ang(ii)))
      0                     vel(ii)*cos(deg2rad(ang(ii)))         sin(deg2rad(ang(ii)))];

      E(:,ii) = Y(:,ii) - H*Xpred(:,ii);

      S = H*CA_PRED_COV*(H.') + J*Sigma_matrix*(J.');

      K = CA_PRED_COV*(H.')*inv(S);

      Xfilt(:,ii) = Xpred(:,ii) + K*E(:,ii);
      CA_PRED_COV = (eye(size(CA_PRED_COV,1))-K*H)*CA_PRED_COV;

      if ii ~= num_samples
          Xpred(:,ii+1) = CA_PHI*Xfilt(:,ii);
          CA_PRED_COV = CA_PHI*CA_PRED_COV*(CA_PHI.') + Q;
      end
  end


so the problem is at the generation of my measurement data

@kms correct, you have to generate the data according to the state space equations, otherwise you might violate the assumptions of the model. If you look at the other comment, your time derivatives might be wrong, but other than that you are probably good to go. Also, see my updated answer.

okay that makes more sense since my data is not suitable for testing the model it is not behaving the way i am expecting i didn't knew the data should be according to the state space equations thank you so much  i will check this and come back again if i have any more doubt

but while testing the CV model also i generated the measurements similar way but the filter results were good why this problem i am encountering in CA model

@kms hard to say for sure, but it could be that the CA model is incorrect.

i generated my measurements as per your suggestions there is a lot of improvement in the filter output i need to fine tune a bit but this gave me little confidence boost so thank you so much

@fibonatic if i have radial velocity as one of the measurements then i can write vx(velocity in x direction) and vy(velocity in y direction)  directly as vx=vcosθ, vy = vsinθ right? i don't have angular velocity to express dx/dt=vcos(θ)−rsin(θ)dθ/dt and dy/dt=vsin(θ)+rcos(θ)dθ/dt.  correct me if i am wrong

@kms No, if you don't know dθ/dt then you can't just ignore those terms for the velocities. There is still a way to use the radial velocity measurement to improve your estimate, but this measurement is a nonlinear function of the states, so you could for example use an extended Kalman filter instead.
